# Migrating to a Nosql DB from Oracle

Tags: mongodb, database-migration, nosql

I have a large code base of an online charging application that is tightly coupled to Oracle and relies extensively on SQL queries , PL/SQL procedures etc.

In case , we are to migrate to a NO SQL based DB , would all the code need to be rewritten or are there some already available libraries/drivers that do the job of translation of sql queries to no-sql queries automatically by simply having us define a mapping between the current Oracle Schema and the new underlying NO-SQL DB schema (designed afresh)?

Thanks

Comment: If it is that tightly coupled, why do you want to change? And NoSQL schemas differ so vastly from RDBMS schemas that I doubt it would make any sense at all to even try to automate this. As for queries, you might want to have a look at razorsql, but this adds an additional layer between the database and your code. All PL/SQL would have to be rewritten, of course and be executed client side. So, please explain what the reasons for migration are.

Comment: There is no such thing as NoSQL. There is only a whole lot of new database technologies which all work completely different. How complicated your migration will be depends on which one you pick. A wrapper might be available, but for most databases it won't work *well*, because most NoSQL databases aren't designed for relational data. When you expect a different database technology to be a drop-in replacement which works just as before (only faster), you will likely be disappointed.

Comment: Thank you Philipp and Markus for your responses.

Comment: Thanks Philipp, Markus for your responses. Main reasons why we are considering migration: the huge subscriber data that we deal; capability to scale horizontally; & more importantly reduce cost. However,main blockade I see here is that it would be really painful to rewrite huge source code to comply with new underlying DB + the effort on redesigning/migrating to new DB schema. Additionally we have well defined soap interfaces as well .  If cost was the only factor would you recommend migrating to something like postgres ? Would that also entail huge effort of rewriting the SQL part ?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to rewrite a lot of things.

Relational database and nosql "things" are so different. And nosql are not transactional, eccept for documents.

You can save money going to mysql or postgresql (suggested) but still you have to implement a lot of things and you need to study proxy, connection pooling when you need to scale.

But, you can save a lot of work with Postgres plus advanced server of enterprise db: http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/products/postgres-plus-advanced-server

They say you can switch db without a single line to be changed. And save money.
Then you can access things like partitioning that will cost a lot in enterprise version of Oracle.